# Compare 2 subclass instances with same super class

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have 2 sub-class (Student, Teacher) and a superclass (Occupation).
I have created Object A from Student and Object B from Teacher.

```
Student A = new Student();
Teacher B = new Teacher();
```

And I already created a static method that takes objects as arguments and returns boolean;

```
compare(A, B);

public static boolean compare(Student s, Teacher t)
```

In the method, I just put this code to compare if both object belong to the same class or not;

```
if (s.getClass() == t.getClass())
```

And now I get the error saying:

```
incomparable types: Class<CAP#1> and Class<CAP#2>
```

where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:

```
CAP#1 extends Student from capture of ? extends Student
CAP#2 extends Teacher from capture of ? extends Teacher
```

What is wrong here ?

NOTE: If I use the comparison s.equals(t), it doesn't have any error at all. Why can't I use the object.getClass() method correctly ?

Comment: A Student is never a Teacher. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I object, Student can be a Teacher simultaneously.

Comment: @VictorSorokin: Java was designed without multiple inheritance. So how is that possible, when both teacher and student extend occupation?

Comment: I know it will never be the same class (logic). But, I have a question (homework) that ask me to use the getClass() method to compare between  2 objects to see if they belong to the same class (returns true) or not (returns false).

Comment: @Seismoid well, this can be smthg like `Student extends Occupation` and `Teacher extends Student`, OP hasn't specified hierarchy exactly. Anyway, I was referring to real-life situation (think graduate students giving lectures to undergraduates).

Comment: @VictorSorokin then the correct model would be `Person has-a Set<Occupation>`. A specific job position cannot be a Student and a Teacher at the same time, but a person can have multiple occupations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
    public static boolean compare(Object o1, Object o2)
```

and then maybe use `instanceof` to compare like `if(o1 instanceof Teacher && o2 instanceof Student)`

The exception is thrown because `getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends Object>` and like the error message tells you, those classes are incomparable because Student and Teacher will return different classes (I think your mistake is to assume there is returned something like a string).

Answer (score 1):

If `class Student extends Occupation` and `class Teacher extends Occupation`, then there is no class that is both a `Student` and a `Teacher`. Thus there's no point in trying to compare them. `s.getClass() == t.getClass()` would always return false.

The compiler can detect that, since, for any type T, `T.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends T>`. `Class<? extends Student>` and `Class<? extends Teacher>` are never equal to each other and thus incomparable.

If you do want to compare them, you need to convince the compiler the types are indeed comparable. You could change the method signature (as suggested by @Seismoid) to `compare( Object o1, Object o2)` or by explicit upcasting to `Class<?>` or even `Class` (I sense a *raw types* warning here) or `Object`:

```
return ((Class<?>) s.getClass()) == ((Class<?>) t.getClass());
```

as per why `s.equals(t)` works, this is because the signature of `T.equals` is `public boolean equals(Object)`, not `public boolean equals(T)`, so the compiler has no way to check the comparison will always return false. Indeed, it may not even return false as you can create an object that equals objects from a different class.

You cannot override `==`, so the compiler *knows* the comparison is immaterial as objects that cannot be the same class cannot be *identical* to each other (unless both are *null* - and you should check that in a different way).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3 says:

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal.

Comment: As I said before, yes by logic, it will surely returns false since Student and Teacher is REALLY in a different class, BUT, my homework question still want to compare them both. Also, why does s.equals(t) works ? Why s.getClass() == t.getClass() does not ?

Comment: @e-zardYusof answered; citing JLS now.

Comment: So what do you think I should to do (what other method) to compare those both classes ?

Comment: @e-zardYusof I already answered that in paragraph #3. Upcast either (or both) class to (at least) `Class<? extends Occupation>`. Alternatively, cast one (or both) arguments to `Occupation` or higher, _then_ take its class.

Comment: @e-zardYusof `return ((Class<?>) s.getClass()) == ((Class<?>) t.getClass());`